# How can I use Stored Procedures with EF Code-First?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm in the middle of optimizing some queries and I'd like to push one of them into a stored procedure, say `spGetUsers`.

I understand how to fetch data from an *existing* stored procedure, but how do I go about ensuring that - using Code-First - `update-database` also imports my procs and updates their contents if needed, handles proc deletion, etc?

Comment: Just copy and past the plain text string into the Up method and call `Sql("heres my proc")`

Comment: @stevenackley - is there any way to have this be automagic, given a list of sprocs in a given folder, delete all existing sprocs and throw the new ones in?

Comment: If it is in the Up method, it'll run when the migration runs. You can put as many procs in there as you want, just script the proper alter or create statements in your sql string.

Comment: @stevenackley your comment should be an answer, actually the accepted answer. I would only add that you cannot forget to add the "undo" scripts in Down(), for the modifications made in Up(). So it will be preferable to create a folder per migration  and drop  all DDL scripts there.

Comment: @E-Bat the overhead there is ridiculous though.  I want a solution where I can keep things business-as-usual - `update-database`.  I haven't dug into the guts yet but maybe there's a way to leverage pre-build events to automatically modify the EF Ups/Downs given a folder of sprocs?

Answer (score 0):

//and updates their contents//

You don't get any auto-magic.  **You** take on the effort of maintaining the stored procedure.

Which is one of the motivating factors for the creation of EF and using EF.  NOT having to maintain .sql files.

Even with the "gets", you still have to maintain if you rename anything.

***Note:EF does not take any mapping into account when it creates entities using the Translate method. It will simply match column names in the result set with property names on your classes.***

(from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to automate any stored procedure updates from within the migration script. I would recommend putting each alter into a separate Sql() method call; in case there is a syntax error, it'll be easier to diagnose.

Whenever the migration is ran, this will will your scripts automatically and be able to revert back in the case of a downgrade.

Additionally, if you needed the script to execute, you could run `Sql("exec dbo.TestProc")`

```
 public override void Up()
    {

        Sql(alterProc);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql(undoProc);
    }

string alterProc = @"ALTER PROCEDURE AS BEGIN dbo.TestProc AS BEGIN SELECT 1 END"
string undoProc= @"ALTER PROCEDURE AS BEGIN dbo.TestProc AS BEGIN SELECT 2 END"
```